# How do I load the html pages on a div when I click in a link (using AJAX AND JQUERY)

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

```
 <div id="menu"> 
  <nav>
  <ul class="nav_links">
    <li><a id ="homelink" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a id="aboutlink" href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a id="locationlink" href="#">Location</a></li>
  </ul>
  
</nav>
</div>

<Main id="main_container">
</Main>
```

Now I need the AJAX AND JQUERY code that when I click on one of the anchors, the content froM a document. HTML is displayed on main_container.

FOR EXAMPLE: CLICK ON HOME LINK>DISPLAY ON MAIN CONTAINER THE CONTENT FROM HOME

Comment: On the HTML code, I forgot to include the tag 
<Main id="main_container">
</Main>

Comment: Please remove your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [jQuery .load() method](https://api.jquery.com/load/) to load the page URL, and [event.preventDefault](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to prevent redirecting to the page itself, like so:

```js
$('#menu .nav_links a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this),
        $href = $this.attr('href');
    $('#main_container').load($href);
});
```

Comment: Would also need preventDefault otherwise would navigate to the url, assuming OP adds a url, it's currently `href="#"`

Comment: @freedomn-m Good catch! I'm getting sloppy.

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
The page still loading on a new page even if I change the # for a link

Comment: I found the mistake, I had to call the script out of the tag<head>.